# SYSTEM user (Windows 2003) through network

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-attached-storage, cifs, network-share

We're trying to connect an email server with a NAS device. Email server runs over Windows 2003 Server and NAS device with Open-E. No "Active Directory", just shared folders with CIFS.

In order to ensure the connection between them, we've changed the user that runs the email server and we've given to him read/write permissions.

The problem comes with Plesk Control Panel wich runs on the email server and lets the users manage his mail domains. With Filemon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642) we've discovered that Plesk retrieves information about the size of the folders with the process 'sysinfo.exe' wich is loaded by the SYSTEM user. As I said before, no active directory, just shared folders with CIFS. Obviously this access results in 'ACCESS DENIED'.

As long as I know, with this schema, problems with permissions are avoided ensuring that users and passwords are identical in both devices. As far as I know, SYSTEM user can't be manipulated in order to achieve this.

Is there any way to get SYSTEM user reading and writing over the NAS?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

The System user has no rights to access across the network and cannot be changed that I'm aware of.  Can you change what user plesk is running as?  if it is IIS hosted, maybe put it in an AppPool with a defined identity?

Comment: actually if the nas device was domain joined then all you have to do is add the domain\machineaccount$ to the share and ntfs perms and it would work fine.